# How to refill a table when it becomes empty

Tags: lua

I try to pick some values without redondance in each round, but I can't fill the table again when it becomes empty.
How to achieve this ?

```
function repete ()
Liste_Choix = Liste_Choix or { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 }
q = table.remove ( Liste_Choix , math.random ( 1 , #Liste_Choix ) ) 
print (q)
end

for i = 1,7 do repete () end
```

Comment: Why removing selected element from the table?  Just move it to the end of the table (to avoid selecting the same value again)

Comment: "move" = `table.remove` + `table.insert`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff If I move it to the end, I could pick it again. Or I want pick each element without redondance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty array (`{}`) is not considered `false`. `or` will only replace the first element with the second element **if it is false.**

You need to specifically check for zero in order to refill the list.

Here's an example:

```lua
local Liste_Choix = {}
function repete ()
    if #Liste_Choix == 0 then
        Liste_Choix = { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 }
    end
    q = table.remove ( Liste_Choix , math.random ( 1 , #Liste_Choix ) ) 
    print (q)
end

for i = 1,7 do repete () end
```